# Don't keep activities option not working

Tags: android, android-activity

Hi I have enabled Don't Keep Activities option under **Developer Settings**.
But it does not seem to be working.

**For example**

Lets say I have an App which launches a browser via intent. By theory since the user have left my app it should kill it right ? But it does not. On pressing back button it takes me to my App.
Please let me know if I have understood this option correctly. If I did, would like to know why it is not working

Comment: When I go to Browser App, onStop will be called on the calling activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Killing an Activity does not mean Closing the app. It just destroys the activity and frees the device resources. When you press back button, the previous activity is recreated again as if it were opened first time.

Answer (score 1):

Using this option is equivalent to using a task killer. Task killers are worse than useless on Android. If you use a task killer, **you’re just slowing down your system by throwing out cached data and forcing Android to load apps from system storage whenever you open them again**.

It will re-generate activity, So **more process than usual**.

Source - https://www.quora.com/Is-the-Dont-keep-activities-option-under-Developer-Settings-really-effective-in-saving-battery

Comment: I came across this article. But my main intention here was just for developing  purpose, to simulate the scenario when android os randomly destroys the app when in background due to memory constraint.

Answer (score 0):

When you use an intent on other activity, the previous one isn`t destroyed. Tne method onStop() is called when you use an intent. You can read about the activity lifecycle and the methods, that are called due to different situations.
So, your activity is stopped but not destroyed!
Also, the **don`t keep activities option** is used for different debugging things. It slows your phone very much. You phone must close the app and then open it again, what is taking a lot of memory and battery usage.

Comment: I am aware of the lifecycle. But if you read about "Don't keep Activities" it says that as soon as user leaves the activity it will destroy it. And I assumed it will destroy the app itself. Hence the confusion. @Vihaari Varma answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to take advantage of it all:

Don't keep activities -> turn on
Background process limit -> No background processes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).